# useApi hook with multiple parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useApi custom hook, that takes an endpoint (url) with multiple parameters.
When one of the parameters changes a graph is rendered.
The problem is that when one parameter changes, another parameter is changing as well and the graph is rendered twice. How can I solve it?
Thanks

```
  const useApi = (endpoint, requestType, body) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ fetchedData: [], isError: false, isFetchingData: false });
    useEffect(() => {
        requestApi();
    }, [endpoint]);
    const requestApi = async () => {
        let response = {};
        try {
            setData({ ...data, isFetchingData: true });
            console.log(endpoint);
            switch (requestType) {
                case 'GET':
                    return (response = await axios.get(endpoint));
                case 'POST':
                    return (response = await axios.post(endpoint, body));
                case 'DELETE':
                    return (response = await axios.delete(endpoint));
                case 'UPDATE':
                    return (response = await axios.put(endpoint, body));
                case 'PATCH':
                    return (response = await axios.patch(endpoint, body));
                default:
                    return (response = await axios.get(endpoint));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            setData({ ...data, isError: true });
        } finally {
            if (response.data) {
                setData({ ...data, isFetchingData: false, fetchedData: response.data.mainData });

            }
        }
    };
    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of places that can be refactored:

First, you can get rid of `data` dependency in your `useEffect` by converting it to something like this:

```js
setData(currentData => {
  return { ...currentData, isFetchingData: true }
})
```

As second and most importantly, you should either move your `requestApi` function to inside of the `useEffect` or wrap it with a `useCallback` function.

And finally, It is totally OK if there are multiple renders followed by another. Because you are depending on all params inside of your `useEffect`.

One thing that you can do is **canceling the axios requests during the unmount** by taking advantage of [returning a function in useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).

So here is the final version of your code:

```js
const useApi = (endpoint, requestType, body) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    fetchedData: [],
    isError: false,
    isFetchingData: false
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    let axiosSource = axios.CancelToken.source() // generate a source for axios
    let didCancel = false // we can rely on this variable.
    const requestApi = async () => {
      let response = {}
      try {
        setData(data => {
          return { ...data, isFetchingData: true }
        })
        console.log(endpoint)
        const axiosOptions = { cancelToken: axiosSource.token }
        switch (requestType) {
          case 'GET':
            return (response = await axios.get(endpoint, axiosOptions))
          case 'POST':
            return (response = await axios.post(endpoint, body, axiosOptions))
          case 'DELETE':
            return (response = await axios.delete(endpoint, axiosOptions))
          case 'UPDATE':
            return (response = await axios.put(endpoint, body, axiosOptions))
          case 'PATCH':
            return (response = await axios.patch(endpoint, body, axiosOptions))
          default:
            return (response = await axios.get(endpoint, axiosOptions))
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        if (!didCancel) {
          setData(data => {
            return { ...data, isError: true }
          })
        }
      } finally {
        // do not update the data if the request is cancelled
        if (response.data && !didCancel) {
          setData(data => {
            return {
              ...data,
              isFetchingData: false,
              fetchedData: response.data.mainData
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
    requestApi()
    // Here we are saying to axios cancel all current ongoing requests
    // since this is the cleanup time.
    return () => {
      didCancel = true
      axiosSource.cancel()
    }
  }, [body, endpoint, requestType])
  return data
}
```

I did not test the code. But it should be working. Please try and tell me what happened.