# useApi hook with params

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the hook useAPI that was describe in the first answer in [useApi hook with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539262/useapi-hook-with-multiple-parameters)
But I have a main problem. In my component I render the useAPI when in the url itself I have paramenters that might not have a value yet, which cause an error. The values comes from a different API call. How can I render my useAPI hook with the params **only** when they are defined?

my code looks like this:

```
const Availability = () => {
     [account, setAccount] = useState(0);
     const savedApiData = useAPI({
         endpoint:'/programs/${state.account.id}/', // The account obj comes from a different useAPI in this component
         requestType: 'POST',
         body: {
            siteIds: !state.siteId ? [] : [state.siteId] 
         }
     }); 
}
```

On the first render the API url will be an error that says "cannot read property "id" of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple, in the fourth line, you're accessing the `id` property of `state.account`, but `account` here is undefined (probably because it doesn't exist). To solve the problem, you could use a dummy id when `state.account` is undefined (but you will definitely end up with a 404 from the server, so you must handle that), or don't use `useApi` at all. Hooks are really hard to tinker with, and sometimes a small unhandled use case for a hook can make it completely useless.

Another idea could be to allow the `endpoint` hook config parameter to be a function (only invoked when requesting), and add another boolean parameter to this object to control wether or not the request should be done.

Then, if `state.account` is undefined, no request is done, the `endpoint` function is never executed and no error occur, and when `state.account` has a value, the hook could re-try to launch the request, call the `endpoint` function and this time you get no error.

**Example (not tested):**

```
const useApi = ({endpoint, requestType, body, doRequest = true}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ fetchedData: [], isError: false, isFetchingData: false });
    useEffect(() => {
        if (doRequest) requestApi();
    }, [endpoint, doRequest]); // Retry request when doRequest's value changes
    const requestApi = async () => {
        // invoke endpoint if it is a function
        let endpointUrl = typeof endpoint === 'function' ? endpoint() : endpoint;
        let response = {};
        try {
            setData({ ...data, isFetchingData: true });
            console.log(endpointUrl);
            switch (requestType) {
                case 'GET':
                    return (response = await axios.get(endpointUrl));
                case 'POST':
                    return (response = await axios.post(endpointUrl, body));
                case 'DELETE':
                    return (response = await axios.delete(endpointUrl));
                case 'UPDATE':
                    return (response = await axios.put(endpointUrl, body));
                case 'PATCH':
                    return (response = await axios.patch(endpointUrl, body));
                default:
                    return (response = await axios.get(endpoint));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            setData({ ...data, isError: true });
        } finally {
            if (response.data) {
                setData({ ...data, isFetchingData: false, fetchedData: response.data.mainData });

            }
        }
    };
    return data;
};
```

Usage:

```
const Availability = () => {
     [account, setAccount] = useState(0);
     const savedApiData = useAPI({
         endpoint: () => '/programs/${state.account.id}/', // Replace string literal with a factory function
         requestType: 'POST',
         body: {
            siteIds: !state.siteId ? [] : [state.siteId] 
         },
         doRequest: !!state.account, // Only request if account exists
     }); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't quite understand your second suggestion about the endpoint callback Can you elaborate with a basic code example?

Comment: I just added an example